# Indentation Last in XML while removing space using Regular expressions in

Tags: c#, xml, regex, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

I am trying to remove whitespace while removing elements which was added to XML while adding elements.

I was able to remove whitespace using Regular expression (we  are using .NEt 2.0)

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@">\s*<");
newconfig = regex.Replace(newconfig, "><");
```

But problem is after Removing whitespace all  will come in one single line, The Indentation added will be removed.

Please let me know how can I Remove whitespace without making change to my indentation?

Comment: Please don't treat XML as just some weirdly formatted string. There are classes built into the [.NET framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145036(v=vs.110).aspx) which should make working with XML a pleasant experience. `Regex` isn't one of them.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse XML use XMLReader [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliver :But How can i Remove whitespace from innertags, as that was done by Regex. i used Regex to remove whitespace which will be created.